# jQuery working different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make a dropdown searchbox with autosuggest and all the code is working fine in Chrome but I'm having a problem in Firefox. The problem is rather strange. When the function is executed in Firefox, the execution goes into the if section when the condition is true but it is not going to the else part if it is not true.

```
$('body').click(function(){
    if($('.search').is(":focus"))
    {
         alert("is focused");
    }
    else if(!($('.search').is(":focus")))
    {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

This is the code I have written. I am not able to understand where it is going wrong, but in Chrome the execution happens smoothly.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Why do you need `if (!($('.search').is(":focus")))`? Just remove this if condition. you don't need to check again

Comment: do you see any error on firefox console?

Comment: @Satpal sir, i tried just `else` statement but even that didnt work.

Comment: What about putting your code (HTML, styles, and JS) into a JSfiddle.net, then we can all fiddle with it. The problem may be somewhere other than the JS.

Comment: @user3624407, Try with `$(document).click(function () {` instead of `$('body').click(function () {`

Comment: It could be a malformation of HTML as well. @jedison is right, create a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2Gh/
this is the JSfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSFiddle (and your code) just works well.

You just didn't noticed that your body doesn't cover the whole page :
[image]

- Green area : body is clicked, field is focused, you get a "is focused"
- Red area : body is clicked, field is not focused, you get a "no"
- Orange area : body is **not clicked**, you get... nothing

Add this CSS to get it work :

```
html,
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you missed the css for html and body:

```
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

It's working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/Wu2Gh/1/

Js:

```
$('body').click(function () {
 if ($('.search').is(":focus")) {
    alert("is focused");
 } else if (!($('.search').is(":focus"))) {
    alert("no");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second condition and just making it `else`. The `else if` doesn't seem necessary because the your condition is a `boolean` - either `true` or `false`.

```
$('body').click( function() {
    if($('.search').is(":focus")) {
         alert("is focused");
    }
    else {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```